# closing cmd after script is finished

Tags: windows, python-3.x, batch-file, cmd, subprocess

I'm using python to run a script from a .bat file that opens a piece of software for data analysis. After the script is finished, the cmd is still open. How do I close it after the script terminates? Currently using:

```
subprocess.Popen('name.bat')
```

Comment: Can you update name.bat?

Comment: not after running it but can amend it as needed before

Comment: `subprocess.Popen` calls WinAPI `CreateProcess`, which executes a .bat script via `cmd.exe /c`. This instance of CMD exits automatically when it's done. Is name.bat starting another instance of CMD?

Comment: good question! I opened it using check_output a moment ago and got a cmd window that closed and another one that opened and run the script. so I guess the answer to your question is yes

Comment: If `name.bat` is using the `START` command to launch a new `CMD` window, find out what it's starting and adjust it to close the window when it's done.

If a batch file wants to force its window to close, it can use the `EXIT` command; but normally that's not needed unless it was started with `CMD /K`.